# Unix mail information - where did it come from?

Tags: email, unix

I'm wondering where some information came from in a message I got on my Mac laptop. Here's the message:

```
From john@leutenberg.horners.org

X-Original-To: john

Delivered-To: john@leutenberg.horners.org

From: john@leutenberg.horners.org (Cron Daemon)

To: john@leutenberg.horners.org

...
```

Where did it get the "john@leutenberg.horners.org" I know my username is john, and my computer is leutenberg, but where did it get the horners.org part?

Answer (score 3):

It may have been provided by your DHCP server.